# Read a file and create multidimensional dictionaries with python

Tags: python

I need to read and store the content of a file inside hierarchical data structure. The file has a structure like this:

```
    [server01]
        Status01 = abc
        Option01 = 123  
        Option02 = testadata0|testadata1|testdata2

    [server02]
        Status01 = def
        Option01 = 456
```

I used to code in Perl, where this was a piece of cake, using Hashes of Hashes; I cannot seem to find a similar approach in python. I have seen examples, where people define dictionaries, like that:

```
    people = {1: {'name': 'Jim', 'age': '24', 'sex': 'Male'},
              2: {'name': 'Claire', 'age': '23', 'sex': 'Female'}}
```

Still, no example for creating the data structure in a loop with data from a file.
Can anyone provide an example.

Just to further illustrate what I mean, this would be the structure in Perl:

```
    %HoH = (
        server01 => {
            Status01 => "abc",
            Option01 => "123",
            Option02 => "testadata0|testadata1|testdata2"
        },
        server02 => {
            Status02 => "def",
            Option01 => "456",

        },
```

Comment: Why is the second server called  `server02` in Perl and `server01` in the config file?

Comment: For future reference the term is "nested dictionary". I googled "Python nested dictionary from file". It's often difficult to know what to search for coming from another language that uses a different vocabulary.

Comment: It's a typo/copy/paste error and should be `server02`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a toml file, i really suggest you to follow Totoro's answer,

But if you want an example on how to read a file and make a dict out of it, here is a complete example

your data.txt file

```
[server01]
Status01 = abc
Option01 = 123  
Option02 = testadata0|testadata1|testdata2
[server02]
Status01 = def
Option01 = 456
```

Your python file

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f: #This allows you to read a file, and automatically close it at the end
    data = {}
    key = None
    for line in f:
        cleaned_line = line.strip('\n') # A lot of special cases, just for the example you strip the line on new cline character

        # Find a new key
        if cleaned_line.startswith('['):
            key = cleaned_line.strip('[').strip(']')
            data[key]={}

        else:
            status, value = cleaned_line.split(' = ') # To simplify our life we can unpack the value as soon as we create the list
            data[key][status] = value
print(data)
# output: {'server01': {'Status01': 'abc', 'Option01': '123  ', 'Option02': 'testadata0|testadata1|testdata2'}, 'server02': {'Status01': 'def', 'Option01': '456'}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the end it is pretty straight forward. I seem to have messed up with setting the `data[key]={}`

Answer (score 0):

You may read the contents of the file into a variable called `file` such that each entry is composed of a string that is the *server number* and a dict that is the *status and option* info. Then just do the following:

```
for data in file:
  hoh[data[0]] = data[1]
```

`BlueSheepToken`'s answer is the completed code. It can be done.

Comment: any reason for the downvote? I tried providing a high-level idea without handing out the completed code.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware that I downgraded you. Do you know, how I can undo it. The "up" arrow does not seem to work.

Comment: you can try it now.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-the-downvote

Comment: I tried the 'hack', but it still won't change